# Swift - Button not clickable after UIView is added

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiview

So, I have a class that creates Confetti subclass of `UIView`, which is run when a high score is reached. But, when the confetti is run, my buttons becomes unclickable, which makes its problematic. When the confetti is not run, my button is clickable and there is no error. Please help me, I been trying to fix this for hours.

Here is my code where Confetti is run:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Score") > UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Highscore") {
confettiView.startConfetti()
        delay(3, completion: {
            confettiView.stopConfetti()
        })
}
```

Here is my code where the Confetti is created:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

public class SAConfettiView: UIView {

    public enum ConfettiType {
        case Confetti
        case Triangle
        case Star
        case Diamond
        case Image(UIImage)
    }

    var emitter: CAEmitterLayer!
    public var colors: [UIColor]!
    public var intensity: Float!
    public var type: ConfettiType!
    private var active :Bool!

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        colors = [UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.40, blue:0.27, alpha:1.0),
        UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.78, blue:0.36, alpha:1.0),
        UIColor(red:0.48, green:0.78, blue:0.64, alpha:1.0),
        UIColor(red:0.30, green:0.76, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0),
        UIColor(red:0.58, green:0.39, blue:0.55, alpha:1.0)]
        intensity = 0.5
        type = .Confetti
        active = false
    }

    public func startConfetti() {
        emitter = CAEmitterLayer()
        emitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: 0)
        emitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
        emitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 1)

        var cells = [CAEmitterCell]()
        for color in colors {
            cells.append(confettiWithColor(color: color))
        }

        emitter.emitterCells = cells
        layer.addSublayer(emitter)
        active = true
    }

    public func stopConfetti() {
        emitter?.birthRate = 0
        active = false
    }

    func imageForType(type: ConfettiType) -> UIImage? {

        var fileName: String!

        switch type {
            case .Confetti:
            fileName = "confetti"
            case .Triangle:
            fileName = "triangle"
            case .Star:
            fileName = "star"
            case .Diamond:
            fileName = "diamond"
            case let .Image(customImage):
            return customImage
        }
       /*
        let path = Bundle(for: SAConfettiView.self).path(forResource: "SAConfettiView", ofType: "bundle")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        let imagePath = bundle?.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "png")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath!)
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
        if let data = data {
            return UIImage(data: data as Data)!
        }
        return nil */
        return UIImage(named: fileName)
    }

    func confettiWithColor(color: UIColor) -> CAEmitterCell {
        let confetti = CAEmitterCell()
        confetti.birthRate = 6.0 * intensity
        confetti.lifetime = 14.0 * intensity
        confetti.lifetimeRange = 0
        confetti.color = color.cgColor
        confetti.velocity = CGFloat(350.0 * intensity)
        confetti.velocityRange = CGFloat(80.0 * intensity)
        confetti.emissionLongitude = CGFloat(M_PI)
        confetti.emissionRange = CGFloat(M_PI_4)
        confetti.spin = CGFloat(3.5 * intensity)
        confetti.spinRange = CGFloat(4.0 * intensity)
        confetti.scaleRange = CGFloat(intensity)
        confetti.scaleSpeed = CGFloat(-0.1 * intensity)
        confetti.contents = imageForType(type: type)!.cgImage
        return confetti
    }

    public func isActive() -> Bool {
        return self.active
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us how you are creating 'confettiView' object and adding in your superview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring your button sub-view to front after you start running confetti.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your new view is obscuring the button view below it. 
Ideally, you should remove the confetti view from its superview inside stopConfetti() method, after everything is finished.